# Running an individual mocha test from VSCode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, mocha.js, istanbul

I have created a [test project](https://github.com/oleersoy/tsmochanyc) that enables Mocha tests to be written in typescript and it also as Istanbul integration via nyc.

All tests can be run via the console statement `npm test`.  I'd also like to be able to run them individually by either right clicking and selecting run test or some other means in VSCode.  So for example if this test [hello.spec.ts](https://github.com/oleersoy/tsmochanyc/blob/master/src/hello.spec.ts) is open in the editor, run just that test.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.only will make the test run on only the specified describe or it statement(s)

```
describe.only('blah blah', function(){
it.only('should...', function() {

//test here

})
})
```

.skip will exclude the specified describe or it statement(s)

```
 describe.skip('blah blah', function(){
it.skip('should...', function() {

//test here

})
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Mocha allows to modify test spec calls (`describe` and `it`) to be prefixed with `f` or `x`, where `f` means **focused** and `x` means **disabled**. Hence by writing `fdescribe()` or `fit()` you focus on this test (case) and ignore (don't run) all others.